# Restoring SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration, restore

Is it necessary to restore system databases of SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008, if I am restoring my other databases from 2000 to 2008?

Comment: Before restore check out your DB compatibility level http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2009/07/21/migration-sql-server-2000-to-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: Normally not, but if you have specific clr/system functions/procs this might be the case. but then you can migrate these stored procs/function/clr yourself and not the whole database. I would suggest you first run the sql server 2008 upgrade advisor, this will give you in detail what you have to do. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11455

Comment: @stijin : Do i need to have sql sql server 2008 and sql server 2000 on the same machine to run Upgrade advisor, as in my current case my 2000 and 20008 server are on different machines..?

Comment: Leave necessary, you can not restore system database backup from SS 2000 to SS 2008

Comment: Nope this is standalone installation, you can put it on any pc that is in the domain that can connect to the instance you want to evaluate

Comment: @stijin : Thanks a lot...few days back i directly restored 1 sql 2000 database to sql server 2008, after restoring it i was unable to change the compatibility to 100 and also was unable to draw database diagram..is it possible to resolve such things.??

Answer (score 2):

No. In fact you can't restore the system databases from a SQL Server 2000 system to a SQL Server 2008 instance. If you did parts of (or the entire) database engine won't work as the SQL Server 2000 system databases are formatted very differently from SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Ok... So that means i just have to  backup all sql 2000 user databases and restore it on sql 2008, and change the compatibility level..is crorect?..what about collation level.??

Comment: Yes you just need to restore the user databases to the new instance and change the compatibility level if you need the higher level compatibility.  There's no need to change the collation.